# ordinary least squares coefficients calculation using np.einsum

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to calculate ordinary least squares coefficients `β` in one `np.einsum` call (using standard formula for OLS coefficient estimates `((X'X)^(-1))X'Y`) given a vector of dependent variable `Y` and a matrix of predictors `X`?

Comment: Maybe you can also provide the formula you want to implement?

Comment: Sorry, should've obviously done that, but can't wrap my head around how to do it with Google Chart API since there is no embedded LaTeX support on stackoverflow. The formula is just usual OLS estimates: ((X'X)^(-1))X'Y. Also edited the title to reflect the question better.

Comment: Please also add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Einsum can only implement multiplication-sum transforms, but no matrix (pseudo-)inverses.

The solution in NumPy would be

```
np.linalg.pinv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y
```